# Can I use HTML to define the GUI for my desktop application?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtabbedpane

Can I use HTML to define the GUI for my desktop application? Specifically, can I use it for a `JTabbedPane`?

I'm pretty competent with HTML, so I want to define how my tabbed pane looks with it. Can it be done, or is HTML only for labels? If you have any resources on this, please give them.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by using HTML in tabbed panes. DYM in the tab of the tabbed pane? If so, yes. But why not try it before asking?

Comment: `Specifically, can I use it for a JTabbedPane?` - I have no idea what that means. Are you talking about the text in the tab of the tabbed pane? In any case, try it and see what happens. If it doesn't work as expected then post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem. If it does work then answer your own question to benefit others.

Comment: *"I'm pretty competent with HTML"* As an aside, if you are competent with current day HTML, you're way ahead of Swing's support to render the same. The Swing HTML rendering engine supports 1) a **subset** of **HTML *3.2***. 2) Very limited CSS 3) No scripting (Java Script).

Comment: I was meaning to use html + css to define the presentation of it, saving me the trouble of putting effort into it, but apparently the answer is no.

Comment: Maybe you need to use JavaFX. See: [Fancy Forms With JavaFX CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/css.htm) or maybe [Using FXML to Create a User Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm).